# how to load data from multiple requests to one store with one model

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am developing a demo application using Last.FM API which will get list of artists for user ( http://www.lastfm.ru/api/show/user.getTopArtists) and for each artist get list of events ( http://www.lastfm.ru/api/show/artist.getEvents).

This list should be connected to dataview. I would like to know how to load data from multiple requests into one store. Each request would have own extraParams (artist name).

Is there any way to do this with store and proxy, without calling many times Ext.Ajax.request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's impossible to declare multiple URLs in your `proxy` config.

The only way (which is quite short) I've known so far is to change your `url` dynamically on the fly, something like this:

`yourStore.getProxy().setUrl('your_new_url');`

Note: also `setReader` if necessary

Comment: thanks, I tried to inherit Rest proxy with overriden buildUrl method, but it didn't work. Your solution is more simple.
Still, I wonder why we should use such hacks

Comment: eventually I found a better solution: instead of using `setUrl`, `setExtraParam` can be used or `setExtraParams`